# Post data from an ASP.NET Webforms website to ASP.NET Core 6 MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, webforms

I have two separated websites, both of them are portal websites, that users must be logged in to use our services. The first one is built with ASP.NET webform and the second is built with ASP.NET Core 6.

How can I post the login username and password from the first website to the second, to let the user auto logged in between the two services, note that the two websites are published on the same server and IIS?

I tried to post data from the first webforms website like this

```
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxx/Login/login" method="post" id="sub" >
         <div style="display:none;">

   <input type="text" value="111111" name="Db_UserName" id="Db_UserName" runat="server"  /> 
             <input type="text" value="222222" name="Password" id="Password" runat="server" /> 
   

       </div>
 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('sub').submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and get the data in the login controller in the second, ASP.NET Core 6 website project like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    TempData["msg"]= model.Db_UserName;
            
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

But I get an error:

> This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
> HTTP ERROR 405

What is the problem? Is there a way to correct this?

Any advise please ...

Comment: As an aside... *Giving* a username and password *to* a user generally isn't a great idea.  That's usually information that's *requested from* a user.  If the goal is to allow them to access the target page without needing to know the login information, why have a login at all?

Comment: As mentioned don't pass username and password as part of your data.  If the user is logged and as you have clarified the sites are on the same server.  Then configure the machine key in web.config and the logged in user context will be shared.